# Is there a way in Java to convert strings to dates that are either MMddyyyy or Mddyyyy?

Tags: java, java-time, date-parsing, date

I've been trying to convert strings to dates. Some of them show up like this: 1011970 (as in January 1, 1970) and some show up like this: 10011970 (as in October 1, 1970). The fact that the month is at the beginning has created a big problem for me.

I have already come up with the solution that I can just check how many digits the number has and use separate formatters, but I would prefer to use something a little more elegant. I have been trying to use the DateTimeFormatterBuilder to create a 'one size fits all' formatter.
Heres an example of something I've tried and the output I've gotten.

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1, 2, SignStyle.NORMAL)
            .appendPattern("ddyyyy")
            .toFormatter();

        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("10011970", formatter));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1011970", formatter));
```

```
Date: 1970-10-01                                                                                                       
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1011970' could not be parsed at index 4      
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)                              
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)                                       
        at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)                                                               
        at Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

So as you can see the above solution works for the first formatted date, but not the second.
Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks in advance!
James

Comment: What about if the length is seven, prepend a "0", and then parse as MMddyyyy?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I thought so at first but at least based on the two examples in the question, the day of the month is *always* two digits.

Comment: @DavidConrad Oops. My mistake.

Comment: Ok, so day is always 2 digits, but the month can be 1-2 digits, I think Elliot's idea has merit. You can "assume", if the length of the format is `6`, then the month < 10 and prepend a `0` to it.  Based on that you can simple use a format of `MMddyyyy`

Comment: Similar: [DateTimeFormatter unable to parse a Date String but SimpleDateFormat is able to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619669/datetimeformatter-unable-to-parse-a-date-string-but-simpledateformat-is-able-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. This works:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
            .toFormatter();

    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("10011970", formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1011970", formatter));
```

And the output is:

> ```
> 1970-10-01
> 1970-01-01
> ```

I don’t know why it doesn’t work when specifying day of month and year through a format pattern, but it doesn’t, I have seen that before.

Other than that the rule of thumb for *adjacent value parsing* (parsing of numeric date-time fields with no separator between them) is that you need to specify exact widths of each field except the first. Then the formatter calculates widths from the back end of the string to find out how many digis to use for the first value (here the month). So your use case fits nicely.