# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020052' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, datetime, kotlin

I'm trying to parse "2020052" with DateTimeFormatter using the format "yyyyMMd" but it throws an error (title), using "yyyyMMdd" throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020052' could not be parsed at index 6`, does anyone know a solution (Other than adding a 0 in front of 2, I'm parsing through a large dataset of many dates), below is my code

```
val format = DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyyMMdd").toFormatter()
date = LocalDate.parse("2020052", format)
```

Comment: You have too few digits in `"2020052"` to parse it with `"yyyyMMdd"` - you need two digits for both month and day: 2020 05 02 — I'm not sure why you'd get the exception when using `"yyyyMMd"`

Comment: This works, although I'm not certain why: `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMd"); Date date = format.parse("2020052");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTimeFormatter unable to parse a Date String but SimpleDateFormat is able to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619669/datetimeformatter-unable-to-parse-a-date-string-but-simpledateformat-is-able-to)

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
            .toFormatter();
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2020052", dateFormatter));
```

Output:

> 2020-05-02

It works only for dates within the first 9 days of each month, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

A generic way of getting LocalDate with 7 or 8 characters.
String dateString = "20200525";

```
    if (dateString.length() > 6 && dateString.length() <= 8) {
        LocalDate dateObj = LocalDate.of(Integer.valueOf(dateString.substring(0, 4)),
                Integer.valueOf(dateString.substring(4, 6)), Integer.valueOf(dateString.substring(6)));
    }
```

Comment: That should work no matter is day of month is 1 or 2 digits (as long as month number is always 2 digits).